# Using "OR" and selection by another table model in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I will explain my question with a concrete example. I have single DynamoDB table (for this example). Table is consisting by the two models:

```
- user: {
firstname
lastname
placeId
typeId
}

// List of favourites for each users
- userFavourites {
userId
favouriteId
favouriteType
}
```

I would like to effectively find users, by the following rule:

`placeId = 'XXX' OR typeId = 'YYY' or user have any favourite with favouriteId: 'ZZZ' and favouriteType: "Dog" OR user have any favourite with favouriteType: "Cat"`

I'm using onetable for communication with dynamo: https://doc.onetable.io/start/quick-tour/

Is it possible to do this kind of selection in DynamoDB (with multiple OR and selection by items from another model in same table) and everything together in one rule?

Answer (score 1):

To be efficient with your reads you must do a GetItem or Query which means you have to provide the partition key for the item, that means you cannot do an `OR` with the native APIs.

You can however do an `OR` using PartiQL `ExecuteStatement` where you can say:

`SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE PARTITIONKEY IN [1,2,3]`

Again this is only useful when it's the partition key.

If you are looking for OR on multiple different values then I suggest perhaps using a more suitable database with more flexible query capability, as to do so with DynamoDB would resul in a full table Scan each time you need a single row/item.

Comment: Thanks Lee, Im very appreciate you fast answer. Im thinking about fill GSI1PK with value, which Im querying alway and GSI1SK with values, where I would like to use OR.

Comment: ....but, If it will be works still I have problem how to query with OR userFavourites. Is it possible to do with single query?

Comment: ...and if not, is it bad approach, to query users and than query userFavourites again for each selected user to check if user has some required favourites? It can be hundreds thousands of users.

Comment: You can Query based on user first, and for that user you can check their favourites. But you cannot check favourites for multiple users without scanning the entire table.

Comment: And isn't it bad approach to make query for each user?

Comment: Yes it would be slow and inefficient. Again, my point here is DynamoDB does not provide you the flexibility to query with multiple conditions and would not be my database of choice giving your use-case.